# Is there pinyin input mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, input-method

I'm learning Chinese and I'm wondering if there is a way to input pinyin easily.

"pinyin" is a word with tone, like "qǐngwèn".

Is there a emacs minor mode for pinyin?

If there is not yet I'll try to write it. But I have only very little knowledge about emacs lisp.

#### Add info

I want to have pinyin input mode itself that can input tone marks easily. I don't need Chinese IME.

Comment: If you are not using Emacs as an operating system, there are implementations to use input method frameworks like `fcitx` in tty. If you are referring to inputting those accented characters, there may be some general methods (well, but not so straightforward as inputing `qing3wen4` and get the thing you want I guess). P.S. I wanted to say US-intl, but it doesn't support all four tone markers… P.P.S. Emacs has a pinyin IM in its 25 Chinese IMs, if you are referring to something that gives you the corresponding 汉字 from pinyin.

Comment: Thanks for info. But I want to use emacs so that I can use the function also in osx and windows. (I may asked the question in wrong forum, but I thought it would be best to ask here about Emacs.)

Comment: Have you found a good way to type pinyin characters in Emacs? I'm still searching. For the meantime I use https://pinyin.typeit.org/ to type pinyin and then copy and paste it to emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has four pinyin input variants, the names start with `chinese-py`. You can set the input method with `C-x enter \` or `M-x set-input-method`, and get a description with `M-x describe-input-method`.

I haven't used any of them, and haven't read all the descriptions, so I don't know the exact difference between the variants.

**Edit**

If you just want to input the diacritical marks above the vowels that are used in pinyin to indicate the tone, you can also use an *input method*. You type two letters for the vowel+mark you want. For example, the method `latin-2-prefix` has

```
'a -> á   `a -> à   ~a -> ă
```

More details with `list-input-methods` and the descriptions, as explained above.

However, as far as I know, there's no pre-defined input method that includes the *macron* ā, but you can define your own method, as explained in [this stackexchange question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/how-do-i-find-out-which-input-modes-include-a-specified-uft-8-character).

Comment: ah, `chinese-py` is a Chinese IME using pinyin. I want to input a pinyin itself with tone marks. So these are different.

Answer (score 1):

[**chinese-sisheng**](https://emba.gnu.org/emacs/emacs/-/blob/e54eeb9bf08ed5920f5b302539f2d8ce97d909e8/leim/quail/sisheng.el) input method allows writing tonal marks to produce good-looking pinyin like below:

```
ni3 -> nǐ
hao3 -> hǎo
nv3 -> nǚ
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tumashu/pyim pyim is the best IME for now.

It's written in Lisp only. So you don't need any extra tools.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is a IME using pinyin. I want to have pinyin input mode that can easily add tone marks.

Comment: You can raise a issue on pyim's web site. Technically it's not difficult.